# How to optimize queryset filtering

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a little bit of code as follows:

```
    for prop in Property.objects.all():
        for platform_device in prop.platformdevice_set.all():
            if platform_device.platform == cur_platform:
                if platform_device.applicable_devices.filter(name=cur_device).exists():
                    if platform_device.applicable_events.filter(name=cur_event).exists():
                        print("Found my correct even and need to continue processing.")
                    else:
                        for group in platform_device.event_group.all():
                            if group.applicable_events.filter(name=cur_event).exists():
                                print("Found my correct even and need to continue processing.")
```

It is a bit messy but it is working so far. Where I am stuck at is this portion:

```
                    if platform_device.applicable_events.filter(name=cur_event).exists():
                        print("Found my correct even and need to continue processing.")
                    else:
                        for group in platform_device.event_group.all():
                            if group.applicable_events.filter(name=cur_event).exists():
                                print("Found my correct even and need to continue processing.")
```

Basically what I am doing is checking the `platform_device.applicable_events` to check if inside of that contains my cur_event. If it does then I need to continue processing from that point.

Else

I am going to look through a event_group (which is just a grouping of events) and checking if cur_event is inside of one of those groups and then continue processing.

My question is how can I make both of those avenues end up in the same spot. I am just trying to prevent having the same code in both of those locations.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do as much work in the database as possible. Instead of "filtering" the queryset in python, filter it in the db.

```
for prop in Property.objects.filter(
    platformdevice__platform=cur_platform,
    platformdevice__applicable_devices=cur_device,
).filter(
    Q(platformdevice__applicable_events=cur_event) 
    | Q(platform_device__event_group__applicable_events__name=cur_event)
):
    #continue processing
```

the `foo__bar=baz` filters a related table `foo` for column `bar` with value `baz`. To filter for value A or B you can use [Q-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/)

- or: `Q(..) | Q(..)`
- and: `Q(..) & Q(..)`  (same as normal filter)

Comment: I tried to look at this and not fully understanding it. I tried to paste it into my code to experiment and I get "positional argument follows keyword argument" error.